# Process multiple messages at once in Azure WebJobs

Tags: .net, azure, message-queue, azure-webjobs, queuetrigger

I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378877/azure-queue-storage-triggered-webjob-dequeue-multiple-messages-at-a-time/44380090#) post to grab multiple messages at once in a single webjob execution (to accumulate the results of multiple messages). However this api: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.GroupQueueTrigger does not provide documentation about, what happens when we fail to process one of the message from the batch downloaded, does it try the whole batch again? or it just moves failed message to poison queue? Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1):

Like Azure Functions, Azure App Service WebJobs with the WebJobs SDK is a code-first integration service that is designed for developers.

Azure Functions is built on the WebJobs SDK, so it shares many of the same event triggers and connections to other Azure services.

When a queue trigger function fails, Azure Functions retries the function up to five times for a given queue message, including the first try. If all five attempts fail, the functions runtime adds a message to a queue named -poison. You can write a function to process messages from the poison queue by logging them or sending a notification that manual attention is needed.

The retry policy executes its child policies once and then retries their execution until the retry condition becomes false or retry count is exhausted.

References: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#Retry

Comment: Thanks Richard! the question is about what happens when we trigger webjobs/functions on batch of queue msgs using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.GroupQueueTrigger and not just a single message in the queue.

Comment: I've check the codes of GroupQueueTrigger from GitHub but I didn't found any thing different about trouble handling.